# How to access local resources using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I want to access the local resources/files which are stored in the web browser when are on a web site. I am trying to generate a dataURI for the images which are loaded whenever we visit a site using JS and print the same in the console log.

NOTE: The image is being downloaded from a remote server and is not stored locally.

Any suggestions/methods to accomplish this? Any method to directly gain access to the .jpeg, .png, etc from the browser resources?

Heres the code of sample website i am trying this on

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image_split</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Splitting images within the browser</h1>
    <br><hr><br>
    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
    <br><hr><br>
    <p id="split_result"></p>

    <br><hr><br>

    <script src="image_split.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is the JS

```
var image_elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

var i;
var count=0;
for(i=0;i<image_elements.length; i++){
    count++;
}

var image = image_elements[0];

/*if(count>0){
    document.getElementById("split_result").innerHTML = image_elements[0];
}*/

//The code below does not work :(
/*
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 100, 100);
document.getElementById("split_result").innerHTML = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
*/
```

I want to access the image stored at image_elements[0] directly from local cache and modify the same with JS.

![link to image]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7UeFzC7IXYaODN0SWhGZlp2dnc/view?usp=sharing

Thanks :)

Comment: If the images are served-up with a Cross-Origin header, you can draw them to a canvas element and then get a dataURL of the image from the canvas.

Comment: @enhzflep i tried doing it with the canvas element but the dataURI/URL getting generated is 1. not valid according to online Base64 validators and 2. is not getting displayed when used as a src for image tags :(

Comment: i have updated the question with the code i tired which has canvas elements. And additionally i noticed that when loding file from remote URL's, the image.width and image.height are returning null values then preventing the dataURL from being generated. So i had commented the two lines which is not shown above

Comment: The problem with the image you're interested in (logo11w.png) is that it is **not** served with a cross-origin header. This means that when it comes time to call the dataURL method of the canvas, you get a security error. Specifically (assuming Chromium/Chrome) "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported." - the way around this is to use a server-side script that requests this image from the original source. You then get the image from your own server, which means you won't get a cross-origin error like you are currently.

Comment: The difficulty you're having with the image dimensions likely come from the image not being loaded at the time you try to get its size. The image takes a fair while to load and is most likely still loading by the time your JS code is loaded and executed. To get around this, run your code inside an event handler that fires when the window's onload event fires. I.e add `window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);`, followed by `function onDocLoaded(evt){ // do stuff here - all resources are known to be loaded };`

Comment: I will try adding the event listener. Thanks :) and any clues as to if we can preload the src from the image tags and store them in a local storage for caching? or is it possible to directly access cache using js?

Answer (score 0):

Heres the solution code to access images from web browser resources without getting 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.'

```
var image_elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

var i;
var count=0;
for(i=0;i<image_elements.length; i++){
    count++;
}

var image = image_elements[0];

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);
function onDocLoaded(evt){ 
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    //canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    var dataModel = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    document.getElementById("split_result").innerHTML = dataModel.data.byteLength;
}
```